# "Checking Account" Java Program

Tags: java, methods

Hello again StackOverflow. I'm back with a new problem in my code. Yes, this is for a school (high school). My problem is this. This is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner moneyTime = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello world!");

    int dep;
    int with;
    int balance = 1200;
    int choice;

    while(1 == 1)
    {
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.printf("%s%d", "Current Balance: $", balance);
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.println("What would you like to do:");
      System.out.println("Type 1 for [DEPOSIT]");
      System.out.println("Type 2 for [WITHDRAWAL]");
      System.out.println("Type 3 for [EXIT/FINAL]");
      choice = moneyTime.nextInt();

      if(choice == 1)
      {
        System.out.print("Amount: ");
        dep = moneyTime.nextInt();
        deposit(balance, dep);
        System.out.println("Testing: " + balance);
      }
      else if(choice == 2)
      {
        System.out.print("Amount: ");
        with = moneyTime.nextInt();
        withdrawl(balance, with);
        System.out.println("Testing2: " + balance);
      }
      else
      {
        exitORfinal();
      }
    }

    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
    {
    int balance1 = balance + dep;
    return balance1;
    }

    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
    {
    int balance1 = balance - with;
    return balance1;
    }

    static int exitORfinal
    {
    System.out.println("Testing Text to make sure thiworks");
    }

  }
}
```

The problem I'm having with the code is that the static at the bottom isn't working and is printing out these errors.

```
exit status 1
Main.java:46: error: illegal start of expression
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
    ^
Main.java:46: error: ';' expected
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
                      ^
Main.java:46: error: <identifier> expected
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
                                   ^
Main.java:46: error: not a statement
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
                                        ^
Main.java:46: error: ';' expected
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
                                           ^
Main.java:52: error: illegal start of expression
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
    ^
Main.java:52: error: ';' expected
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
                         ^
Main.java:52: error: <identifier> expected
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
                                      ^
Main.java:52: error: not a statement
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
                                           ^
Main.java:52: error: ';' expected
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
                                               ^
Main.java:58: error: illegal start of expression
    static int exitORfinal
    ^
Main.java:58: error: ';' expected
    static int exitORfinal
                          ^
12 errors
exit status 1
Main.java:46: error: illegal start of expression
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
    ^
Main.java:46: error: ';' expected
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
                      ^
Main.java:46: error: <identifier> expected
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
                                   ^
Main.java:46: error: not a statement
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
                                        ^
Main.java:46: error: ';' expected
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep)
                                           ^
Main.java:52: error: illegal start of expression
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
    ^
Main.java:52: error: ';' expected
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
                         ^
Main.java:52: error: <identifier> expected
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
                                      ^
Main.java:52: error: not a statement
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
                                           ^
Main.java:52: error: ';' expected
    static int withdrawal(int balance, int with)
                                               ^
Main.java:58: error: illegal start of expression
    static int exitORfinal
    ^
Main.java:58: error: ';' expected
    static int exitORfinal
                          ^
12 errors
```

I'm seriously confused. I understand that I am probably missing something or I am just completely blind to an obvious error. I don't know what to do and I tried everything that I know. I would ask the teacher but she quite legitmately is an ass and will help literally no one even if we've asked other students.

Thank you again for you help (if I do get any).

Comment: You're declaring methods inside of `main`, which isn't allowed in Java. Put those other methods outside of `main`, at the class scope. Think of it this way, those methods should belong to the class, not to another method.

Comment: Also you forgot the `()` after `static int exitORfinal`.

Answer (score 0):

**First** you need to move all methods that you created in main method to out of the main method, 
**Second** you need add some parameter to exitORfinal static method for example:  exitORfinal()  {  .. }
**Third** you must replace moneyBoi variable to moneyTime, because you declared as moneyTime.
**Fourth** you must rename withdrawal method to withdrawl.

And your code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    static int exitORfinal() {
        System.out.println("Testing Text to make sure thiworks");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner moneyTime = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello world!");

        int dep;
        int with;
        int balance = 1200;
        int choice;

        while (1 == 1) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.printf("%s%d", "Current Balance: $", balance);
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("What would you like to do:");
            System.out.println("Type 1 for [DEPOSIT]");
            System.out.println("Type 2 for [WITHDRAWAL]");
            System.out.println("Type 3 for [EXIT/FINAL]");
            choice = moneyTime.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.print("Amount: ");
                dep = moneyTime.nextInt();
                deposit(balance, dep);
                System.out.println("Testing: " + balance);
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.print("Amount: ");
                with = moneyTime.nextInt();
                withdrawl(balance, with);
                System.out.println("Testing2: " + balance);
            } else {
                exitORfinal();
            }
        }
    }    

    static int deposit(int balance, int dep) {
        int balance1 = balance + dep;
        return balance1;
    }

    static int withdrawl(int balance, int with) {
        int balance1 = balance - with;
        return balance1;
    }
}
```

1. **For fixing first** : need to know that all methods are declared in a
   class  and no in a method. [defining methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)
2. **For fixing second** : need to know any method needs some parameter, even empty someMethod() { ... } [defining methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)
3. **For fixing third and fourth** : need to be aware on naming of methods that you created, this has to be the same naming for calling it on any method.

Answer (score 0):

How about this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    static int deposit(int balance, int dep) {
        return balance + dep;
    }

    static int withdrawl(int balance, int with) {
        return balance - with;
    }

    static void exitORfinal() {
        System.out.println("Testing Text to make sure thiworks");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner moneyTime = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello world!");

        int dep;
        int with;
        int balance = 1200;
        int choice;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.printf("%s%d", "Current Balance: $", balance);
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("What would you like to do:");
            System.out.println("Type 1 for [DEPOSIT]");
            System.out.println("Type 2 for [WITHDRAWAL]");
            System.out.println("Type 3 for [EXIT/FINAL]");
            choice = moneyTime.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.print("Amount: ");
                dep = moneyTime.nextInt();
                deposit(balance, dep);
                System.out.println("Testing: " + balance);
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.print("Amount: ");
                with = moneyTime.nextInt();
                withdrawl(balance, with);
                System.out.println("Testing2: " + balance);
            } else {
                exitORfinal();
            }
        }
    }    


}
```

I think putting these static methods before the `main` method is better.

Answer (score 0):

Just to state the problem in plain english:
The declaration of your various methods (exitORfinal, withdrawal, deposit) are *inside* the declaration of your main method. In java, methods cannot be defined inside of another method body, you have to move them up to your class' body.

Also, may I advise you to use an efficient IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, or any decent editor with Java plugins such as VSCode or SublimeText)? It would underline the problem nicely and even suggest fixes.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, static means that it's a variable/method of a class, it belongs to the whole class but not to one of its certain objects.

This means that static keyword can be used only in a 'class scope' i.e. it doesn't have any sense inside methods.

Now if you have a static variable inside a method,then that variable comes under the method's scope,not class's scope,and JVM is unable to allocate memory to it,because a method is called by the help of class's object,and that is at run-time,not at class loading time. You can do something like this:

```
    public Class YourClass {
      static int someNumber = 5;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(someNumber);
      }
    }
```